# Public Method called Pause : Function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function in a JS file:

```
// publicc methos: pauses the slideshow
    pause : function() {

        if( this.isPlaying ) {

            this._stopSlideshow();

        }
```

How can I call this function from other JS files?

****Update****

Plugin JS File:

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

var $event = $.event,
$special,
resizeTimeout;

$special = $event.special.debouncedresize = {
    setup: function() {
        $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args = arguments,
            dispatch = function() {
                // set correct event type
                event.type = "debouncedresize";
                $event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
            };

        if ( resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
        }

        execAsap ?
            dispatch() :
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $special.threshold );
    },
    threshold: 50
};

// ======================= imagesLoaded Plugin ===============================
// https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

// $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
// execute a callback when all images have loaded.
// needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

// callback function gets image collection as argument
//  this is the container

// original: mit license. paul irish. 2010.
// contributors: Oren Solomianik, David DeSandro, Yiannis Chatzikonstantinou

// blank image data-uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
var BLANK = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

$.fn.imagesLoaded = function( callback ) {
    var $this = this,
        deferred = $.isFunction($.Deferred) ? $.Deferred() : 0,
        hasNotify = $.isFunction(deferred.notify),
        $images = $this.find('img').add( $this.filter('img') ),
        loaded = [],
        proper = [],
        broken = [];

    // Register deferred callbacks
    if ($.isPlainObject(callback)) {
        $.each(callback, function (key, value) {
            if (key === 'callback') {
                callback = value;
            } else if (deferred) {
                deferred[key](value);
            }
        });
    }

    function doneLoading() {
        var $proper = $(proper),
            $broken = $(broken);

        if ( deferred ) {
            if ( broken.length ) {
                deferred.reject( $images, $proper, $broken );
            } else {
                deferred.resolve( $images );
            }
        }

        if ( $.isFunction( callback ) ) {
            callback.call( $this, $images, $proper, $broken );
        }
    }

    function imgLoaded( img, isBroken ) {
        // don't proceed if BLANK image, or image is already loaded
        if ( img.src === BLANK || $.inArray( img, loaded ) !== -1 ) {
            return;
        }

        // store element in loaded images array
        loaded.push( img );

        // keep track of broken and properly loaded images
        if ( isBroken ) {
            broken.push( img );
        } else {
            proper.push( img );
        }

        // cache image and its state for future calls
        $.data( img, 'imagesLoaded', { isBroken: isBroken, src: img.src } );

        // trigger deferred progress method if present
        if ( hasNotify ) {
            deferred.notifyWith( $(img), [ isBroken, $images, $(proper), $(broken) ] );
        }

        // call doneLoading and clean listeners if all images are loaded
        if ( $images.length === loaded.length ){
            setTimeout( doneLoading );
            $images.unbind( '.imagesLoaded' );
        }
    }

    // if no images, trigger immediately
    if ( !$images.length ) {
        doneLoading();
    } else {
        $images.bind( 'load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded', function( event ){
            // trigger imgLoaded
            imgLoaded( event.target, event.type === 'error' );
        }).each( function( i, el ) {
            var src = el.src;

            // find out if this image has been already checked for status
            // if it was, and src has not changed, call imgLoaded on it
            var cached = $.data( el, 'imagesLoaded' );
            if ( cached && cached.src === src ) {
                imgLoaded( el, cached.isBroken );
                return;
            }

            // if complete is true and browser supports natural sizes, try
            // to check for image status manually
            if ( el.complete && el.naturalWidth !== undefined ) {
                imgLoaded( el, el.naturalWidth === 0 || el.naturalHeight === 0 );
                return;
            }

            // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src, but only when
            // dealing with IE, or image is complete (loaded) and failed manual check
            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            if ( el.readyState || el.complete ) {
                el.src = BLANK;
                el.src = src;
            }
        });
    }

    return deferred ? deferred.promise( $this ) : $this;
};

// global
var $window = $( window ),
    Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

$.Slicebox = function( options, element ) {

    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );

};

$.Slicebox.defaults = {
    // (v)ertical, (h)orizontal or (r)andom
    orientation : 'v',
    // perspective value
    perspective : 1200,
    // number of slices / cuboids
    // needs to be an odd number 15 => number > 0 (if you want the limit higher, change the _validate function).
    cuboidsCount : 5,
    // if true then the number of slices / cuboids is going to be random (cuboidsCount is overwitten)
    cuboidsRandom : false,
    // the range of possible number of cuboids if cuboidsRandom is true
    // it is strongly recommended that you do not set a very large number :)
    maxCuboidsCount : 5,
    // each cuboid will move x pixels left / top (depending on orientation). The middle cuboid doesn't move. the middle cuboid's neighbors will move disperseFactor pixels
    disperseFactor : 0,
    // color of the hidden sides
    colorHiddenSides : '#222',
    // the animation will start from left to right. The left most cuboid will be the first one to rotate
    // this is the interval between each rotation in ms
    sequentialFactor : 150,
    // animation speed
    // this is the speed that takes "1" cuboid to rotate
    speed : 600,
    // transition easing
    easing : 'ease',
    // if true the slicebox will start the animation automatically
    autoplay : false,
    // time (ms) between each rotation, if autoplay is true
    interval: 3000,
    // the fallback will just fade out / fade in the items
    // this is the time fr the fade effect
    fallbackFadeSpeed : 300,
    // callbacks
    onBeforeChange : function( position ) { return false; },
    onAfterChange : function( position ) { return false; },
    onReady : function() { return false; }
};

$.Slicebox.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slicebox.defaults, options );

        this._validate();

        // all the items
        this.$items = this.$el.children( 'li' );

        // total number of items
        this.itemsCount = this.$items.length;
        // if there's no items return
        if(this.itemsCount === 0 ) {

            return false;

        };

        // suport for css 3d transforms and css transitions
        this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d;

        // current image index
        this.current = 0;

        // control if the slicebox is animating
        this.isAnimating = false;

        // control if slicebox is ready (all images loaded)
        this.isReady = false;

        // preload the images
        var self = this;
        this.$el.imagesLoaded( function() {

            // we need to hide the items except first one (current default value)
            var $current = self.$items.eq( self.current ).css( 'display', 'block' ).addClass( 'sb-current' );

            // get real size of image
            var i = new Image();
            i.src = $current.find( 'img' ).attr( 'src' );
            self.realWidth = i.width;

            // assuming all images with same size
            self._setSize();
            self._setStyle();
            self._initEvents();

            self.options.onReady();
            self.isReady = true;

            if( self.options.autoplay ) {

                self._startSlideshow();

            }

        });

    },
    _validate           : function( options ) {

        if( this.options.cuboidsCount < 0 ){

            this.options.cuboidsCount = 1;

        }
        else if( this.options.cuboidsCount > 15 ) {

            this.options.cuboidsCount = 15;

        }
        else if( this.options.cuboidsCount %2 === 0 ) {

            ++this.options.cuboidsCount;

        }

        if( this.options.maxCuboidsCount < 0 ){

            this.options.maxCuboidsCount = 1;

        }
        else if( this.options.maxCuboidsCount > 15 ) {

            this.options.maxCuboidsCount = 15;

        }
        else if( this.options.maxCuboidsCount %2 === 0 ) {

            ++this.options.maxCuboidsCount;

        }

        if( this.options.disperseFactor < 0 ) {

            this.options.disperseFactor = 0;

        }

        if( this.options.orientation !== 'v' && this.options.orientation !== 'h' && this.options.orientation !== 'r' ) {

            this.options.orientation = 'v';

        }

    },
    _setSize : function() {

        var $visible = this.$items.eq( this.current ).find( 'img' );

        this.size = {
            width   : $visible.width(),
            height  : $visible.height()
        };

    },
    _setStyle : function() {

        // max-width is the real size of the images
        this.$el.css( {
            'max-width' : this.realWidth
        } );

    },
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        $window.on( 'debouncedresize.slicebox', function( event ) {

            // assuming all images with same size
            self._setSize();

        } );

    },
    _startSlideshow: function() {

        var self = this;

        this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {

            self._navigate( 'next' );

            if ( self.options.autoplay ) {

                self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.interval );

    },
    _stopSlideshow: function() {

        if ( this.options.autoplay ) {

            clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
            this.isPlaying = false;
            this.options.autoplay = false;

        }

    },
    _navigate : function( dir, pos ) {

        if( this.isAnimating || !this.isReady || this.itemsCount < 2 ) {

            return false;

        }

        this.isAnimating = true;

        // current item's index
        this.prev = this.current;

        // if position is passed
        if( pos !== undefined ) {

            this.current = pos;

        }
        // if not check the boundaries
        else if( dir === 'next' ) {

            this.current = this.current < this.itemsCount - 1 ? this.current + 1 : 0;

        }
        else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

            this.current = this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.itemsCount - 1;

        }

        // callback trigger
        this.options.onBeforeChange( this.current );

        if( !this.support ) {

            this._fade( dir );

        }
        else {

            this._layout( dir );
            this._rotate();

        }

    },
    _fade : function( dir ) {

        var self = this,
            $visible = this.$items.eq( this.prev ),
            h = $visible.find( 'img' ).height();

        this.$el.css( 'height', h );
        this.$items.css( 'position', 'absolute' );

        this.$items.eq( this.current ).fadeIn( this.options.fallbackFadeSpeed, function() {

            $( this ).css( 'display', 'block' ).addClass( 'sb-current' );
            self.$el.css( 'height', 'auto' );
            self.$items.css( 'position', 'relative' );
            self.isAnimating = false;

        } );
        self.$items.eq( self.prev ).removeClass( 'sb-current' ).fadeOut( this.options.fallbackFadeSpeed );

    },
    _layout : function( dir ) {

        // create a structure like this and append it to the main container (this.$el):
        // <div>    wrapper with perspective
        //   <div>
        //     <div></div> front side
        //     <div></div> back side
        //     <div></div> right side
        //     <div></div> left side
        //     <div></div> top side
        //     <div></div> bottom side
        //   </div>
        //   <div>..</div>
        //   <div>..</div>
        //   <div>..</div>
        //   ...    number of slices defined in options
        // </div>

        var orientation = this.options.orientation;

        if( orientation === 'r' ) {

            orientation = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 ) === 0 ? 'v' : 'h';

        }

        if( this.options.cuboidsRandom ) {

            this.options.cuboidsCount = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.options.maxCuboidsCount + 1 );

        }

        this._validate();

        var boxStyle = {
                'width' : this.size.width,
                'height' : this.size.height,
                'perspective' : this.options.perspective + 'px'
            },
            config = $.extend( this.options, {
                size : this.size,
                items : this.$items,
                direction : dir,
                prev : this.prev,
                current : this.current,
                o : orientation
            } ),
            self = this;

        this.$box = $('<div>').addClass( 'sb-perspective' ).css( boxStyle ).appendTo( this.$el );

        this.cuboids = [];

        this.$el.css( 'overflow', 'visible' );

        for( var i = 0; i < this.options.cuboidsCount; ++i ) {

            var cuboid = new $.Cuboid( config, i );

            this.$box.append( cuboid.getEl() );

            this.cuboids.push( cuboid );

        }

    },
    _rotate : function() {

        // hide current item
        this.$items.eq( this.prev ).removeClass( 'sb-current' ).hide();

        for( var i = 0; i < this.options.cuboidsCount; ++i ) {

            var cuboid = this.cuboids[ i ],
                self = this;

            cuboid.rotate( function( pos ) {

                if( pos === self.options.cuboidsCount - 1 ) {

                    self.$el.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );
                    self.isAnimating = false;
                    self.$box.remove();
                    var $current = self.$items.eq( self.current );
                    $current.css( 'display', 'block' ); // show() makes it inline style
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $current.addClass( 'sb-current' );
                    } , 0 );
                    self.options.onAfterChange( self.current );

                }

            });

        }

    },
    _destroy : function( callback ) {

        this.$el.off( '.slicebox' ).removeData( 'slicebox' );
        $window.off( '.slicebox' );
        callback.call();

    },
    // public methos: adds more items to the slicebox
    add : function( $items, callback ) {

        this.$items = this.$items.add( $items );
        this.itemsCount = this.$items.length;

        if ( callback ) {

            callback.call( $items );

        }

    },
    // public method: shows next image
    next : function() {

        this._stopSlideshow();
        this._navigate( 'next' );

    },
    // public method: shows previous image
    previous : function() {

        this._stopSlideshow();
        this._navigate( 'prev' );

    },
    // public method: goes to a specific image
    jump : function( pos ) {

        pos -= 1;

        if( pos === this.current || pos >= this.itemsCount || pos < 0 ) {

            return false;

        }

        this._stopSlideshow();
        this._navigate( pos > this.current ? 'next' : 'prev', pos );

    },
    // public method: starts the slideshow
    // any call to next(), previous() or jump() will stop the slideshow
    play : function() {

        if( !this.isPlaying ) {

            this.isPlaying = true;

            this._navigate( 'next' );
            this.options.autoplay = true;
            this._startSlideshow();

        }

    },
    // publicc methos: pauses the slideshow
    pause : function() {

        if( this.isPlaying ) {

            this._stopSlideshow();

        }

    },
    // public method: check if isAnimating is true
    isActive : function() {

        return this.isAnimating;

    },
    // publicc methos: destroys the slicebox instance
    destroy : function( callback ) {

        this._destroy( callback );

    }

};

$.Cuboid = function( config, pos ) {

    this.config = config;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.side = 1;
    this._setSize();
    this._configureStyles();

};

$.Cuboid.prototype = {

    _setSize : function() {

        this.size = {
            width : this.config.o === 'v' ? Math.floor( this.config.size.width / this.config.cuboidsCount ) : this.config.size.width,
            height : this.config.o === 'v' ? this.config.size.height : Math.floor( this.config.size.height / this.config.cuboidsCount )
        };
        // extra space to fix gaps
        this.extra = this.config.o === 'v' ? this.config.size.width - ( this.size.width * this.config.cuboidsCount ) : this.config.size.height - ( this.size.height * this.config.cuboidsCount );

    },
    _configureStyles : function() {

        // style for the cuboid element
        // set z-indexes based on the cuboid's position
        var middlepos = Math.ceil( this.config.cuboidsCount / 2 ),
            positionStyle = this.pos < middlepos ? {
                zIndex : ( this.pos + 1 ) * 100,
                left : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width * this.pos : 0,
                top : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? 0 : this.size.height * this.pos
            } : {
                zIndex : (this.config.cuboidsCount - this.pos) * 100,
                left : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width * this.pos : 0,
                top : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? 0 : this.size.height * this.pos
            };

        // how much this cuboid is going to move (left or top values)
        this.disperseFactor = this.config.disperseFactor * ( ( this.pos + 1 ) - middlepos );

        this.style = $.extend( {
            '-webkit-transition' : '-webkit-transform ' + this.config.speed + 'ms ' + this.config.easing,
            '-moz-transition' : '-moz-transform ' + this.config.speed + 'ms ' + this.config.easing,
            '-o-transition' : '-o-transform ' + this.config.speed + 'ms ' + this.config.easing,
            '-ms-transition' : '-ms-transform ' + this.config.speed + 'ms ' + this.config.easing,
            'transition' : 'transform ' + this.config.speed + 'ms ' + this.config.easing
        }, positionStyle, this.size );

        this.animationStyles = {
            side1 : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.height / 2 ) + 'px )' } : { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.width / 2 ) + 'px )' },
            side2 : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.height / 2 ) + 'px ) rotate3d( 1, 0, 0, -90deg )' } : { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.width / 2 ) + 'px ) rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, -90deg )' },
            side3 : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.height / 2 ) + 'px ) rotate3d( 1, 0, 0, -180deg )' } : { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.width / 2 ) + 'px ) rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, -180deg )' },
            side4 : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.height / 2 ) + 'px ) rotate3d( 1, 0, 0, -270deg )' } : { 'transform' : 'translate3d( 0, 0, -' + ( this.size.width / 2 ) + 'px ) rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, -270deg )' }
        };

        var measure = ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.height : this.size.width;

        this.sidesStyles = {
            frontSideStyle : {
                width : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width + this.extra : this.size.width,
                height : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.height : this.size.height + this.extra,
                backgroundColor : this.config.colorHiddenSides,
                transform : 'rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, 0deg ) translate3d( 0, 0, ' + ( measure / 2 ) + 'px )'
            },
            backSideStyle : {
                width : this.size.width,
                height : this.size.height,
                backgroundColor : this.config.colorHiddenSides,
                transform : 'rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, 180deg ) translate3d( 0, 0, ' + ( measure / 2 ) + 'px ) rotateZ( 180deg )'
            },
            rightSideStyle : {
                width : measure,
                height : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.height : this.size.height + this.extra,
                left : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width / 2 - this.size.height / 2 : 0,
                backgroundColor : this.config.colorHiddenSides,
                transform : 'rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, 90deg ) translate3d( 0, 0, ' + ( this.size.width / 2 ) + 'px )'
            },
            leftSideStyle : {
                width : measure,
                height : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.height : this.size.height + this.extra,
                left : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width / 2 - this.size.height / 2  : 0,
                backgroundColor : this.config.colorHiddenSides,
                transform : 'rotate3d( 0, 1, 0, -90deg ) translate3d( 0, 0, ' + ( this.size.width / 2 ) + 'px )'
            },
            topSideStyle : {
                width : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width + this.extra : this.size.width,
                height : measure,
                top : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? 0 : this.size.height / 2 - this.size.width / 2,
                backgroundColor : this.config.colorHiddenSides,
                transform : 'rotate3d( 1, 0, 0, 90deg ) translate3d( 0, 0, ' + ( this.size.height / 2 ) + 'px )'
            },
            bottomSideStyle : {
                width : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? this.size.width + this.extra : this.size.width,
                height : measure,
                top : ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? 0 : this.size.height / 2 - this.size.width / 2,
                backgroundColor : this.config.colorHiddenSides,
                transform : 'rotate3d( 1, 0, 0, -90deg ) translate3d( 0, 0, ' + ( this.size.height / 2 ) + 'px )'
            }
        };

    },
    getEl : function() {

        this.$el = $('<div/>').css( this.style )
                .css( this.animationStyles.side1 )
                .append( $('<div/>').addClass('sb-side').css( this.sidesStyles.frontSideStyle ) )
                .append( $('<div/>').addClass('sb-side').css( this.sidesStyles.backSideStyle ) )
                .append( $('<div/>').addClass('sb-side').css( this.sidesStyles.rightSideStyle ) )
                .append( $('<div/>').addClass('sb-side').css( this.sidesStyles.leftSideStyle ) )
                .append( $('<div/>').addClass('sb-side').css( this.sidesStyles.topSideStyle ) )
                .append( $('<div/>').addClass('sb-side').css( this.sidesStyles.bottomSideStyle ) );

        this._showImage( this.config.prev );

        return this.$el;

    },
    _showImage : function( imgPos ) {

        var sideIdx,
            $item = this.config.items.eq( imgPos ),
            imgParam = {
                'background-size' : this.config.size.width + 'px ' + this.config.size.height + 'px'
            };

        imgParam.backgroundImage = 'url(' + $item.find( 'img' ).attr('src') + ')';

        switch( this.side ) {

            case 1 : sideIdx = 0; break;
            case 2 : sideIdx = ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? 4 : 2; break;
            case 3 : sideIdx = 1; break;
            case 4 : sideIdx = ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? 5 : 3; break;

        };

        imgParam.backgroundPosition = ( this.config.o === 'v' ) ? - ( this.pos * this.size.width ) + 'px 0px' : '0px -' + ( this.pos * this.size.height ) + 'px';
        this.$el.children().eq( sideIdx ).css( imgParam );

    },
    rotate : function( callback ) {

        var self = this, animationStyle;

        setTimeout(function() {

            if( self.config.direction === 'next' ) {

                switch( self.side ) {
                    case 1 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side2; self.side = 2; break;
                    case 2 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side3; self.side = 3; break;
                    case 3 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side4; self.side = 4; break;
                    case 4 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side1; self.side = 1; break;
                };

            }
            else {

                switch( self.side ) {
                    case 1 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side4; self.side = 4; break;
                    case 2 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side1; self.side = 1; break;
                    case 3 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side2; self.side = 2; break;
                    case 4 : animationStyle = self.animationStyles.side3; self.side = 3; break;
                };

            }

            self._showImage( self.config.current );

            var animateOut  = {}, animateIn = {};

            if( self.config.o === 'v' ) {

                animateOut.left = '+=' + self.disperseFactor + 'px';
                animateIn.left = '-=' + self.disperseFactor + 'px';

            }
            else if( self.config.o === 'h' ) {

                animateOut.top = '+=' + self.disperseFactor + 'px';
                animateIn.top = '-=' + self.disperseFactor + 'px';

            }

            self.$el.css( animationStyle ).animate( animateOut, self.config.speed / 2 ).animate( animateIn, self.config.speed / 2 , function() {

                if( callback ) {

                    callback.call( self, self.pos );

                }

            });

        }, this.config.sequentialFactor * this.pos + 30 );

    }

};

var logError = function( message ) {

    if ( window.console ) {

        window.console.error( message );

    }

};

$.fn.slicebox = function( options ) {

    var self = $.data( this, 'slicebox' );

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            if ( !self ) {

                logError( "cannot call methods on slicebox prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;

            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( self[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {

                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for slicebox self" );
                return;

            }

            self[ options ].apply( self, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            if ( self ) {

                self._init();

            }
            else {

                self = $.data( this, 'slicebox', new $.Slicebox( options, this ) );

            }

        });

    }

    return self;

};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

My JS File:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#sb-slider').bind('mouseover', function () { 
//pause slide
 })
 });
```

Comment: Like any other method/function: `obj.pause();`.

Comment: Please show us the whole file.

Comment: is it from a widget? or a plugin? please share the context

Comment: Done. Felix, that didnt work. Arun, it's a plugin

Comment: There are a lot of issues with that code, its also now too much work to read to begin to figure out which issues are blocking you. I don't think bergi expected quite such a long file. Help people help you - What have you tried?

Comment: i tried: 1) pause(); 2) object.pause(); 3) Slicebox._stopSlideshow; 4)  Slicebox._stopSlideshow();
I think i need to give a reference where _stopSlideshow function is...but i have no idea how to do that

Comment: You can try `$('selector').slicebox('pause')` - but the plugin implementation is buggy

Comment: @subrui it is because the implementation is buggy try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hhr6x/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny i add this to the original JS file or to mine?

Comment: you need to replace the `$.fn.slicebox = function( options ) {` from the above code with the one I gave - Disclaimer: Not tested

Comment: Ok, i did it, dont know how to pause or stop the slider